# How do you load csv file to Dask properly?

Tags: python, dask

I am lost at how to load CSV file using Dask.

I have hundreds of CSV files that I need to load at once. Loading with pandas doesn't work because it's very large and will take a lot of RAM to do that.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
all_ddf = dd.read_csv("path/part-*", header=None, blocksize="10MB")
```

The code above could run just fine, it didn't run into any error. But when I try to perform a very simple command, it would instantly run into error.

```
all_ddf.head()
```

> ValueError: Mismatched dtypes found in `pd.read_csv`/`pd.read_table`.
>
> +--------+--------+----------+ | Column | Found  | Expected |
>   +--------+--------+----------+ | 1      | object | float64  | | 2      | object | float64  | | 4      | object | int64    |
>   +--------+--------+----------+
>
> The following columns also raised exceptions on conversion:
>
> - 1   ValueError("could not convert string to float: '\\N'",)
> - 2   ValueError("could not convert string to float: '\\N'",)
> - 4   ValueError("invalid literal for int() with base 10: '26023,26022'",)
>
> Usually this is due to dask's dtype inference failing, and
>   *may* be fixed by specifying dtypes manually by adding:
>
> dtype={1: 'object',
>          2: 'object',
>          4: 'object'}
>
> to the call to `read_csv`/`read_table`.

I don't know what I did wrong. And I am not familiar with Dask to understand what went wrong. I don't know if this is even the proper way to load csv file using python.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is in the error message that Dask provided

> Usually this is due to dask's dtype inference failing, and may be fixed by specifying dtypes manually by adding:

```
dtype={1: 'object', 2: 'object', 4: 'object'}
```

> to the call to read_csv/read_table.